# Integer linear programming can't find global minimum

Tags: mathematical-optimization, project-euler

I was working with [Project Euler Problem 418](https://projecteuler.net/problem=418) using Mathematica and got in trouble.

I wrote a function to find the unique factorization triple which minimizes c / a for integer n.

```
FactorizationTriple[n_] := 
 Block[{factor, base, exponent, l, e, varmat, vars, cons1, cons2, cons3, solve, a, b, c},
  factor = FactorInteger[n];
  base = factor[[All, 1]];
  exponent = factor[[All, 2]];
  l = Length[factor];
  varmat = Table[e[i, j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, l}];
  vars = Flatten[varmat];
  cons1 = Thread[0 <= vars];
  cons2 = Thread[exponent == Total[varmat, {1}]];
  cons3 = {varmat[[1]].N[Log[base]] <= varmat[[2]].N[Log[base]] <= varmat[[3]].N[Log[base]]};
  solve = FindMinimum[{varmat[[3]].N[Log[base]] - varmat[[1]].N[Log[base]], Join[cons1, cons2, cons3], Element[vars, Integers]}, vars];
  a = Times @@ (Power @@@ ({base, Table[e[1, j], {j, 1, l}] /. solve[[2]]}\[Transpose]));
  b = Times @@ (Power @@@ ({base, Table[e[2, j], {j, 1, l}] /. solve[[2]]}\[Transpose]));
  c = Times @@ (Power @@@ ({base, Table[e[3, j], {j, 1, l}] /. solve[[2]]}\[Transpose]));
  {a, b, c}]
```

Since both *f* and *cons* in `FindMinum` are linear, I thought it uses `Method->"LinearProgramming"` and I expected it to return a global minimum.

`FactorizationTriple` does work when n = 165 or 100100 or 20!, but it can't give me the correct answer when n = 43!:

```
AbsoluteTiming[FactorizationTriple[43!]]
{1044.17, {392385912744443904, 392388272221065120, 392389380337500000}}
```

The correct answer is `{a, b, c} = {392386762388275200, 392388272221065120, 392388530688000000}`.

**Questions:**

1. Should I use `NMinimize` or `LinearProgramming` instead? (I had some try but failed.)
2. How to set the options in `FindMinimum`?
3. How to improve the efficiency of `FactorizationTriple`? (It's too slow now.)

Comment: For starters, `N[Log[base]]` instances in `cons3` convert exact values to inexact ones, causing loss of precision in the process. Have you tried without the enclosing `N`? (Secondly `FindMinimum` is not guaranteed to find a global minimum, `Minimize` does so.)

Comment: @Kirma For ILP `FindMinimum` should find the global min, but as you suggest, this is subject to numeric issues (the library in question uses machine arithmetic to solve relaxed subproblems). Based on the sizes of the result integers, I rather suspect this is the underlying issue.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I stand corrected. I was actually suspecting this would be the case, but in general it's not a safe assumption... :)

Comment: @kirma I had tried without `N` before, but even if it calculate it for 1 hour, I can't get the result.